# Upload multipart/form-data to S3 from lambda (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to upload multipart/form-data file to S3 using Nodejs.

I have tried various approaches but none of them are working. I was able to write content to S3 from lambda but when the file is downloaded from S3, it was corrupted.

Can someone provide me a working example or steps that could help me?

Thanking you in anticipation.

Please suggest another alternative if you think so.

Following is my lambda code:

```
export const uploadFile = async event => {
  const parser = require("lambda-multipart-parser");
  const result = await parser.parse(event);
  const { content, filename, contentType } = result.files[0];
  const params = {
    Bucket: "name-of-the-bucket",
    Key: filename,
    Body: content,
    ContentDisposition: `attachment; filename="${filename}";`,
    ContentType: contentType,
    ACL: "public-read"
  };

  const res = await s3.upload(params).promise();
  return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            docUrl: res.Location
        })
    };
}
```

Comment: Show your code, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande I have added the code...

Comment: I've faced a similar issue, ultimately, your best bet would probably changed the file to Base64 string and send over to Lambda and convert it back to file before you upload to S3.

Read more here: https://medium.com/@olotintemitope/how-to-upload-files-to-amazon-s3-using-nodejs-lambda-and-api-gateway-bae665127907

Comment: I need a file upload for various file types.
png, jpg, pdf, doc,docx, .xls, csv and so on.

Answer (score 7):

If want to upload file through lambda, one way is to open your AWS API Gateway console.

Go to

"API" -> {YourAPI} -> "Settings"

There you will find "Binary Media Types" section.

Add following media type:

> multipart/form-data

Save your changes.

Then Go to "Resources" -> "proxy method"(eg. "ANY") -> "Method Request" -> "HTTP Request Headers" and add following headers "Content-Type", "Accept".

Finally deploy your api.

For more info visit: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html

Comment: Oof. This. I forgot to hit "Deploy API" after modifying the Resources and Binary Media Types.. ugh.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible points of failure - Lambda receives corrupted data or you corrupt data while sending it to S3.

Sending multipart/form-data content to Lambda is not straightforward. You can see how to do that [here](https://medium.com/@nickolay.laptev/aws-lambda-as-form-submit-handler-6bed9fbceced).
After you did this and you're sure your data is correct in Lambda, check if you send it to S3 correctly (see S3 docs and examples for that).

Comment: There are two things.

One I need to setup Binary Media Types on AWS gateway.
and second parser.

Comment: @KedarShinde can you tell me more about parser