# Convert multipart/form-data file in REST request body to Email Attachment format in Serverless Node.js

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, smtp, multipartform-data, email-attachments

I want to create a REST API which allows a requestor to PATCH multipart/form-data containing a file. The server extracts the file and sends by SMTP as an email attachment. I have the following code:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

const username = 'email account'
const password = 'email password'
const smtpHost = 'mailhog'
const smtpPort = 1025

module.exports.endpoint = (event, context, callback) => {

    const mailOptions = {
        from: 'wat@address.com',
        to: 'inbox@address.com',
        subject: 'Here is a file',
        text: 'Please see attached'
    };

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
        host: smtpHost,
        port: smtpPort,
        secure: false,
        auth: {
            user: username,
            pass: password
        }
    }));

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            const response = {
                statusCode: 500,
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    error: error.message,
                }),
            };
            callback(null, response);
        }
        const response = {
            statusCode: 202,
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
            },
            body: "Accepted",
        };
        callback(null, response);
    });
}
```

Is there a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Using [aws-lambda-multipart-parser](https://github.com/myshenin/aws-lambda-multipart-parser) I was able to do this quite simply:

```
use strict';

const multipart = require('aws-lambda-multipart-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

const username = 'email account'
const password = 'email password'
const smtpHost = 'mailhog'
const smtpPort = 1025

module.exports.endpoint = (event, context, callback) => {
    const file = multipart.parse(event, true).file;

    const mailOptions = {
        from: 'wat@address.com',
        to: 'inbox@address.com',
        subject: 'Here is a file',
        text: 'Please see attached',
        attachments: [
            {
                filename: file.filename,
                content: file.content,
                contentType: 'image/png'
            }
        ]
    };

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
        host: smtpHost,
        port: smtpPort,
        secure: false,
        auth: {
            user: username,
            pass: password
        }
    }));

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            const response = {
                statusCode: 500,
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    error: error.message,
                }),
            };
            callback(null, response);
        }
        const response = {
            statusCode: 202,
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
            },
            body: "Accepted",
        };
        callback(null, response);
  }
```

Comment: This approach will corrupt the file. 
look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59900888/upload-multipart-form-data-to-s3-from-lambda-nodejs