# File upload to S3 has different size than original file

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, nestjs, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm uploading an image from HTML -> NodeJS -> S3

I'm using the `@aws-sdk/client-s3` library. I'm having an issue where uploading the image doesn't appear to be working correctly.

The file size on disk is 111KB, but when I upload it, S3 shows the file size almost doubled at 200Kb.

When I download it from S3, the image doesn't want to open.

Here's my controller code in NodeJs

```
import { AWS_BUCKET, AWS_S3_CLIENT } from '@api/constants';
import { PutObjectCommand, PutObjectCommandInput, S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { Controller, Inject, Post, UploadedFiles, UseInterceptors } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FilesInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { Multer } from 'multer';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
    constructor(
        @Inject(AWS_BUCKET) private bucket: string,
        @Inject(AWS_S3_CLIENT) private client: S3Client,
    ) {}

    @Post('upload-image')
    @UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('files[]', 1, { limits: { fileSize: 10000000 } }))
    async uploadSubmission(@UploadedFiles() files: Express.Multer.File[]) {

        for (let ix = 0; ix < files.length; ix++) {
            const file = files[ix];

            const uploadParams: PutObjectCommandInput = {
                Bucket: this.bucket,
                Key: file.originalname,
                Body: file.buffer,
            };

            await this.client.send(new PutObjectCommand(uploadParams));
        }
    }
}
```

The file uploads to S3 without any error, but you can see from this picture that the file sizes are very different. And if you try to download it, the image won't open.

[image]

I've even tried writing the file to disk (which works and opens correctly). To me, it seems it's an issue between NodeJs and AWS upload.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Turns out it was the api gateway that was the culprit. It wasn't treating `multipart/form-data` as binary. I updated my yaml file to include the binary media type and now everything works as expected.

Credit to this SO [Upload multipart/form-data to S3 from lambda (Nodejs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59900888/upload-multipart-form-data-to-s3-from-lambda-nodejs)

```
ClientApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
        StageName: api
        BinaryMediaTypes:
            - 'multipart/form-data'
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. How do you get this to work in local using serverless-offline?