# Files Uploaded to S3 do not open

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multer

I was developing nodejs api to upload file to my AWS s3. I followed some online articles and using the code below. The files (images/word/pdf) get successfully uploaded to s3. However they do not open. Or give error when downloading and opening in local. One thing noticed here is that files uploaded through my web app have the metadata content-type:"application/octet-stream" while files uploaded manually to s3 have metadata content-type:"image/jpeg". Am I missing something. Here is my nodejs api:

```js
    app.post("/uploadfile", upload.single("file"), async (req, res) => {
      try {
        console.log(req.file);
        var file = req.file;
    
        const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file.path);
    
        const params = {
          Bucket: bucketName,
          Key: file.originalname,
          Body: fileStream,
        };
        const result = await s3.upload(params).promise();
        return res.status(200).send({
          ok: true,
          message: "File upload successful",
          location: result.Location,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send({
          ok: false,
          message: "Failed to upload file. Error: " + err.message,
        });
      }
    });
```

Front end code:

```
const [file, setFile] = useState();
  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    const fileData = new FormData();
    fileData.append("file", file);

    const uploadResult = await uploadFile(fileData);
    console.log(uploadResult);
}

const uploadFile = async (data) => {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    body: data,
  };
  const endPoint = DEV_API_URL + "uploadfile";
  const response = await fetch(endPoint, requestOptions);
  const responseJson = await response.json();
  return responseJson;
};
```

Comment: Have you verified that the uploaded byte content is correct and it's simply the lack of an appropriate content-type header that's the issue?

Comment: It looks like the byte content is not correct. When opening an image I get "this is not a vaild bitmap file, or its format is not currently supported". Word Files give similar error. and pdf files go blank. However their size seems correct

Comment: A better way to validate the file content is to download it and do a checksum vs. the original (correct) file. Or hex dump it and compare at least the beginning and ending bytes. Also, determine the source file's content type and then supply that in ContentType when calling upload.

Comment: Are they not open, or they open as blank page?

Comment: Images, Word files give error. PDF files open but have no content.

Comment: Have you tried adding ```ContentType``` to your ```params``` object? I had a similar problem where signed URL uploads were of octet-stream type when it wasn't explicitly specified, but this was in GCS not S3 so I assume it's a similar issue. You can refer to the full parameters here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally found the solution to my problem. Adding multipart/form-data in my API Gateway settings resolved the issue. Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74063244/file-upload-to-s3-has-different-size-than-original-file)

Answer (score 0):

Configure Multer to store files in memory:

```js
const multer = require('multer');

const upload = multer({
  storage: multer.memoryStorage(),
});
```

Now, pass the file buffer directly to the s3. Also, add `ContentType` to the options:

```
app.post("/uploadfile", upload.single("file"), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.file);
    const file = req.file;

    const params = {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: file.originalname,
      Body: file.buffer,
      ContentType: file.mimetype
    };
    const result = await s3.upload(params).promise();
    return res.status(200).send({
      ok: true,
      message: "File upload successful",
      location: result.Location,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send({
      ok: false,
      message: "Failed to upload file. Error: " + err.message,
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have tried but it does not work. it looks like there is something wrong with the content of the file that is uploaded. I am using multer. const multer = require("multer"); const upload = multer({ dest: "uploads/photos/" });

Comment: Wait, you are uploading it to the server in the `uploads/photos/` folder, and then you are uploading it from server to s3? Do you need it on the server at all? Why don't you upload the buffer directly to the s3?

Comment: I seen tutorials where they follow this approach. How can you upload directly to s3 from the server? Also it looks like the size of files uploaded to s3 are slightly more than their actual size. I am attaching front end code as well.

Comment: You can, just configure Multer to not upload to the server, but to keep buffer in memory. Then, just pass the buffer to the s3. With the current approach, your files will be uploaded to the server unnecessary.

Comment: Ok will try that. But the problem is of files getting corrupted when uploaded. Somehow the file content is not preserved.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Can you try it now?

Comment: Image uploads. But does not open.

Comment: Are you sure you have correct policy attached to the s3 bucket?

Comment: Hmmm... I just noticed you have the error in your frontend code too. `fileData.append("upload", file);` should be `fileData.append("file", file);` because you specify that Multer should expect the input with name "file" in the middleware.

Comment: Sorry! That was "file". Made typo mistake when copying code here. Have changed it.

Comment: The image file in s3 gives this error: File will not be displayed because is it either binary, an unsupported text encoding